# How to pass one prop as a variable to another prop in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, react-props

May I know how to pass a prop as a variable to another prop passed to the child component?

So in parent component I use pass two props "name" and "formProps" to a child like this:

```
<FormField name="id" formProps={formProps} />
<FormField name="amount" formProps={formProps} />
```

In className of the Child Component, I want to make the {props.name} as a variable to the {props.formprops.errors}, but I don't know how to.

I want it be like this:

When "name" prop equals to "id",

```
props.formProps.errors.`${props.name}`
```

is

```
 props.formProps.errors.id
```

When "name" prop equals to "amount",

```
props.formProps.errors.`${props.name}`
```

is

```
 props.formProps.errors.amount
```

But there's error. May I know how should I write it? Thank you so much!

```
const FormField = (props) => {
return (
......
<Field
   type="text"
   name={props.name}

   className={props.formProps.errors.`${props.name}` && props.formProps.touched.`${props.name}` ? 'is-invalid form-control' : 'form-control'}
/>
)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to do it like this

```
className={props.formProps.errors[props.name] && props.formProps.touched[props.name] ? 'is-invalid form-control' : 'form-control'}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you so much for your help! May I know what is the theory behind it and why I can't use `${}`? Thank you so much!!

Comment: I just edited the answer, is the updated the one that worked for you or the old on?

Comment: className={props.formProps.errors[props.name] && props.formProps.touched[props.name] ? 'is-invalid form-control' : 'form-control'} I'm using this one and it works. May I know what's the other one?

Comment: When accessing  an object you pass the property name in [property name] to access the value of said property in the object. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much! May I know why I can't use this template string'${}'?

Comment: You don't need template literal and its Javascript expression here (`${}`). You already have a Javascript expression, which is `className={}`. `{}` is your expression here. So, you can use this and reach the `props.formProps.errors` properties with variables using `[]`. This is how answer owner uses it as`props.formProps.errors[props.name]`

Comment: The template string syntax is to print a JavaScript variable as a part of a string, for example if you have pass a prop like customClass={'custom_classname'} and then you want to use it in your component you use it like this className={`'first_class ${props.customClass}'`}'

Comment: I tried wrapping it in backticks  but it doesn't allow me so replace the quotes className={'first_class ${props.customClass}'} with backticks, Hope this helps.

Comment: @devserkan Thank you so much! That's very helpful!

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer Thank you so much for your help! :D